Issues with new input system
Code:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 5f;
    private Vector2 moveInput;

    public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        moveInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log($"Move Input (performed): {moveInput}");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
        Debug.Log($"Move Input in Update: {moveInput}");
    }

    void MovePlayer()
    {
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(moveInput.x, 0, moveInput.y) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(move, Space.World);
    }
}

I trying to learn how to use new input system in unity - without success.
Im using tutorial and before switched to new inout system, everything works fine.
Now - logs with Move Input were correct (changing from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0 when press or release button).
But I can't make my player move, because in Fixed Update both values were always 0.
What im doing wrong?
I checked other topics but these solutions don't work for me, because they're using rigid body. I don't want to use it in this case.
#Edit
I achived something similar to it by doing it this way:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
 
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 6f;
    private Vector2 moveInput;
    private InputAction moveAction;
 
    void Awake()
    {
        moveAction = GetComponent<PlayerInput>().actions["Move"];
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        moveInput = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        MovePlayer();
        Debug.Log($"Move Input in Update: {moveInput}");
    }
 
    void MovePlayer()
    {
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(moveInput.x, 0, moveInput.y) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(move);
    }
}
 

And i preffer to do it this way, but for knowledge i want to know how to make it work by using mapping through OnMove.

In order for your callback function to be executed, you need to subscribe to event(s).
Create an instance of PlayerInput, enable it and subscribe to the appropriate events for the action.  Replace actionMap below to the name of your action map.
If you have multiple inputs you want to use in various places throughout your code, make sure you use a single instance of PlayerInput.  The easiest way is to implement the Singleton pattern in another file eg. PlayerInputBehaviour or on your Player class if you have one.
In OnEnable, subscribe to the performed and canceled events.
In OnDisable, unsubscribe from those events.
private PlayerInput playerInput;
private Vector2 moveInput;

private void OnEnable()
{
    if (playerInput == null) playerInput = new PlayerInput();

    playerInput.Enable();

    playerInput.actionMap.moveAction.performed += OnMoveActionPerformed;
    playerInput.actionMap.moveAction.canceled += OnMoveActionCanceled;
    playerInput.actionMap.moveAction.Enable();
}
private void OnDisable()
{
    if (playerInput == null) return;

    playerInput.actionMap.moveAction.performed -= OnMoveActionPerformed;
    playerInput.actionMap.moveAction.canceled -= OnMoveActionCanceled;
    playerInput.actionMap.moveAction.Disable();
}

private void OnMoveActionPerformed(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    moveInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}
private void OnMoveActionCanceled(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    moveInput = Vector2.zero;
}

Performed is used here to store the input value, while canceled is used to reset the stored input value.

Code looks understandable, but still don't know how to connect it from unity. I just pasted this code into my mover file and player controls stopped working again.

Try using an instance of your PlayerInput class, I will update with a sample.
